# How can I repair a broken jewel case?

Tags: home, music

I have a jewel case in which a cd came. The tab in the corner is broken:

[image]

The tab is gone, so the front falls off whenever opening the case.

I've tried using duct tape, clear tape, etc. and the problem is that it doesn't hinge. What can I use to reform a hinge?

Comment: I have to ask: Is fixing this really worth it?

Comment: I don't have another case on hand, and to replace the whole case would cost a few dollars. I'd rather fix what I have, even if it doesn't *quite* work perfectly.

Comment: Replacements are very cheap. I would not fix, but replace with a CDR case for a disk I no longer use.

Comment: Regardless of the reason, OP wants to fix the case. We should respect that idea and help find solutions to this problem for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments a few people agreed that you really cannot fix this. I agree, even if you still had the broken piece gluing it back on would involve purchasing a plastic glue that would cost as much as the diamond case, and the glued joint would be nowhere as strong as the original hinge.

But you do need options and here are my suggestions.

Sooner or later you will come across a diamond case. You might see CDs or DVDS at a garage sale for cheap. You might loose one of your CDS and find you have a spare, a friend may have on laying around. You might pick one up at the goodwill for a quarter.

Until then use a rubber band to keep the case intact and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Break the other hinge.  Apply duct tape to the lid and tray and wrap excess around back of case.  Be sure to only create a living hinge without excess tape along the sides.  You want free movement.

Answer (score 0):

1) Straighten a paper-clip
2) Bend the tip to fit into the tiny hole in the bottom of the jewel case at the right depth
3) Use some 5-minute epoxy and *carefully* affix the paperclip along the edge of the case where the broken piece used to be, with the lid closed and the tip of the paper clip in the hole.
4) When the epoxy is set, you may bend the clip toward the hole to give a slight amount of tension

Voila.